# Trocar a imagem com um clique em vários registros

Tags: javascript, imagem, script

Estou com um pequeno problema em JavaSscript.
Tenho uma tabela com várias linhas, em cada linha tem dados e um check no final da linha que, quando clicado, muda a imagem. Muito similar as listagem do Joomla, quem conhece, entenderá.

Até consegui, aqui mesmo o script que muda a imagem, mas, muda em uma linha só.
Como fazer para que o evento ocorra em todas as linhas?

Segue o código:

```js
  function test() {

    if (document.pic1.src == 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png') {

      document.pic1.src = 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Close_Icon_Dark-32.png';

    } else if (document.pic1.src == 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Close_Icon_Dark-32.png') {

      document.pic1.src = 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png';
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>


</head>

<body>
  <form action="#">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Zé Mané</td>
        <td>
          <img name="pic1" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png" onclick="test()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>João das Paçocas</td>
        <td>
          <img name="pic2" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png" onclick="test()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Carlão Pé de Burro</td>
        <td>
          <img name="pic3" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png" onclick="test()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zezão Mão de Entortar Cano</td>
        <td>
          <img name="pic4" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png" onclick="test()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Quem puder me dizer como faço, desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que fiz foi criar dois `arrays` com as seguintes funcionalidades:

- Um `array checked` que mantém o estado de `checked` ou `unchecked` usando um valor booleano. Este valor permitirá colocar a imagem correspondente ao estado `checked` ou `unchecked`.
- Um `array pics` mantém a referência para o elemento de imagem no qual será modificada a `src`.

Para indicar qual seria o botão que foi clicado, inclui na `function test` um parâmetro com um valor inteiro.
Este método é chamado com `0/1/2/3` correpondente à imagem clicada.
Usei a numeração começada em 0 e não em 1 para corresponder à indexação do `array`.

```js
  var checked = new Array(4).fill(true);

  function test(picNumber) {
    var baseUrl = 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/';
    var pics = document.querySelectorAll("img[name^='pic']");
    if(checked[picNumber]){
        pics[picNumber].src = baseUrl + 'Close_Icon_Dark-32.png';
        checked[picNumber] = false;
    }
    else{
        pics[picNumber].src = baseUrl + 'Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png';
        checked[picNumber] = true;
    }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>


</head>

<body>
  <form action="#">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Zé Mané</td>
        <td>
          <img name="pic1" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png" onclick="test(0)" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>João das Paçocas</td>
        <td>
          <img name="pic2" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png" onclick="test(1)" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Carlão Pé de Burro</td>
        <td>
          <img name="pic3" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png" onclick="test(2)" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zezão Mão de Entortar Cano</td>
        <td>
          <img name="pic4" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png" onclick="test(3)" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Olá, MauroAlmeida!!!
Obrigado por responder!!!
É isto mesmo que eu preciso, mas, tenho uma dúvida num detalhe.

A tabela contem até 50 linhas. como resolver esta linha do teu código:

var pics = [document.pic1, document.pic2, document.pic3, document.pic4];

Pq, aqui, pelo que entendi, vc cria uma Matrix com 4 elementos. No caso de 50, como isto poderia ser resolvido???

Comment: @DécioRocha fiz desaparecer essa linha do código e usei um seletor. No array checked tem de ter a quantidade certa de valores, no caso de 50 teria de ter 50 valores.

Comment: Olá MauroAlmeida.
Era exatamente isto que eu precisava.
Agradeço sua pronta resposta.
Fique com DEUS.

Muito Obrigado!!!

Comment: Se a minha resposta o ajudou a resolver o seu problema coloque-a como a resposta aceite.

Comment: Foi mal, não sabia!!!

Comment: @DécioRocha  ainda não colocou como resposta aceite cara.

Comment: @DécioRocha veja aqui como [aceitar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Comment: Poxa, simples e legal!!! 
Gostei!!!

Answer (score 2):

Basta usar um *event handler* `onclick` (não precisa usar um atributo de evento `onclick` em cada imagem). Então, remova todos os `onclick="test()"` das imagens e use:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   // busca todas as imagens cujo name começa com "pic"
   var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img[name^='pic']");
   // percorre todas as imagens e cria um event handler onclick em cada uma
   for(var x = 0; x < imgs.length; x++){
      imgs[x].onclick = function(){
         // pega o src da imagem clicada
         var icon = this.src;
         // alterna entre um ícone e outro
         if(/Tick_Mark/.test(icon)){
            this.src = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Close_Icon_Dark-32.png";
         }else{
            this.src = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png";
         }
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>Zé Mané</td>
     <td>
       <img name="pic1" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>João das Paçocas</td>
     <td>
       <img name="pic2" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Carlão Pé de Burro</td>
     <td>
       <img name="pic3" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Zezão Mão de Entortar Cano</td>
     <td>
       <img name="pic4" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-32.png"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Olá Sam!!!
Obrigado pela resposta. Peço desculpas, mas, não vi que vc tinha postado.

Comment: Poderia me informar como faço o "Aceite" da resposta do Mauro???